# Смена прозрачности спрайта в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Как в инспекторе изменить прозрачность Sprit'а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В поле цвета `Sprite Renderer`'а поменять альфу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]